# Epsilon-delta limit proof, but delta turns out to be negative

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-writing, epsilon-delta

Have to prove that $$\lim_{x \to 0} \sqrt{4-x} = 2$$ Using epsilon-delta definition. So have to show that $\forall\varepsilon>0, \exists\delta>0$ such that $0<|x|<\delta \Rightarrow |\sqrt{4-x}-2|<\varepsilon$. When you work it out you get that $\delta = -\varepsilon^2+4\varepsilon$. What I don't understand is that, if you plug in $\varepsilon=5$ you get $\delta = -5$. But 1) what does it even mean to have negative $\delta$ and 2) you should be able to plug in any nonnegative $\varepsilon$ and get a nonnegative $\delta$ by definition, so why does it not happen in this case?

Comment: When you get $\delta=-\epsilon^2+4\epsilon,$ I think you used $\epsilon<2.$ So you cannot let $\epsilon=5$ for this $\delta.$

Comment: So you have to specify that ϵ<2? But what is δ for ϵ >= 2?

Comment: If $\varepsilon\geq 2$, just choose $\delta=0.1$. It doesn't matter, what you choose exactly for $\delta$, if $\varepsilon$ was large.

Comment: The largest $|\sqrt{4-x} - 2|$ can possibly be is $2$ when $x = 0$. Thus, we only have to worry about the case when $\epsilon \leq 2$. For  $\epsilon > 2$, any $\delta > 0$ would work. So if you want a $\delta$ that works for all $\epsilon > 0$, you can use what @Jochen suggested: $$\delta = \begin{cases}
-\epsilon^2 + 4\epsilon & 0 < \epsilon \leq 2 \\
0.1 & \epsilon > 2
\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you did not post how you found expression for $\delta$, here is what I think:$|\sqrt{4-x}-2|=|\frac{-x}{\sqrt{4-x}+2}|<|\frac{\delta}{\sqrt{4-x}+2}|<|\frac{\delta}{2}|=\frac{\delta}{2}<\epsilon \implies \delta = 2\epsilon$

Comment: That's not correct. From your expression I can choose $x=7$ since $|0-7|\lt 10$. But then $\sqrt{4-7}$ is an imaginary number. The correct answer can't be $\delta\gt 4$

Comment: @Andrei: Thanks for the comment. Don't we need to take domain into account. i.e $x \le 4$? One can take $x=-10$ and the inequality will be satisfied.

Comment: The $\varepsilon-\delta$ definition does not explicitly require it, so you need to put it in yourself. So a correct way to say it is the $\delta=\min(4, 2\varepsilon)$